# Graph API App cannot be found in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, admin

I've created a `Microsoft Graph API App` to read/write Presence and Calendar states of authenticated users. The app works great in two tenants (1 productive, 1 test), but in a few others, the **app cannot be found** through the `Enterprise Application` search nor the `Azure AD Gallery`, but this wasn't a problem for the two tenants it works.

When trying to directly accessing the link to the application, it works on one tenant, while the other shows a 404 error:
[image]

When trying to authenticate with the Connector app on the two tenants where we cannot find the app in the Azure portal, the user can login, approve the scopes, but then lands on the "Need admin approval" page as expected and as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

What do I need to change to **make the app visible inside** the Azure Portal for admin approval?

Few more thoughts:

- One idea I've had is that the app is not verified yet, and it's not possible since I've created the app from a personal Microsoft Account, not a Microsoft Work account. But since it works on other (work) tenants, I figured this couldn't be the problem?
- Nonetheless, I've created a test-app with a Microsoft Work account that is also unverified (since this would require a MPN ID), but it can also not be found in these tenants.
- I am not sure if a `Graph API App` is even an 'Enterprise App`
- A challenge is further that I don't have direct access to these other tenants, since it's a third-party that wants to test that app.
- Note that signInAudience is set to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

Answer (score 0):

> I've created the app from a regular Microsoft Account, not a Microsoft
> Work account. But since it works on other (work) tenants.

If you have given "signInAudience":
"AzureADMultipleOrgs",  it works for other tenants but they are work
accounts so it will work for tenants signed in with work acocunts.

For the app to work for personal accounts , change the
**`"signInAudience" to "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`**, in **manifest** of the app registration.

***Manifest.***

```
{
        "id": "8f8xxxb91",
        "acceptMappedClaims": null,
        "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
        "addIns": [],
        "allowPublicClient": null,
        "appId": "952xgjhkhhklkjo61",
        "appRoles": [],
        "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
        "createdDateTime": "2023-05-01T10:03:51Z",
        "description": null,
        "cx
        "oauth2Permissions": [
           ...],
        "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
        "optionalClaims": null,
        "o...m",
        "replyUrlsWithType": [],
        "requiredResourceAccess": [
            {
                "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
                "resourceAccess": [
                    {
                        "id": "e1fe6dd8xxx88639da4683d",
                        "type": "Scope"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "samlMetadataUrl": null,
        "signInUrl": null,
        "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
        "tags": [],
        "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
    }
```

[image]

Check if you  have following Application.Read.All,Calendars.ReadWrite, Openid,Profile User.Read application and delegated permissions.

Grant admin consent In portal itself , in order not to show evrytime while login for the desired users.

[image]

Check if the app has been added to the Azure AD gallery or Enterprise applications for the specific tenant .It may take some time.

Then the app can be logged in with user credentials  .

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! The signInAudience is already `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`.  I'd love to grant admin consent in the portal itself, but cannot find it directly in the Azure tenant (not by searching nor by accessing the direct link to the app). It can also not be found in the Azure AD gallery/enterprise apps list? How do I add it there? Could it be that it can only be installed when an admin-user goes through the authentication workflow themselves?

Comment: Elsewhere, I just got a hint to use the `admin consent workflow` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent This worked well in my test-tenant, and I am now testing it with two more external tenants. I'll update this thread once I know more